# Allow anyone to insert data into an existing MS SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, input, insert

I am looking to see if it is possible at all to allow to have anyone at all either push an Excel file or anything like that, into the following statement:

```
WHERE FM.ClientsFileNumber IN (
'599554607'

)
```

I want to be able to have anyone input File numbers into that without giving them access to SQL.

Comment: If you tried hard enough, sure.  However, remember to follow the golden rule of validating all user input, no matter how you receive it.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk  Dan's comment is not only a good idea for saving your user's time, it also could be important for *security*, if you're actually using their input to build a SQL command.  Otherwise, you'd surprised what an accessor could get into, using "SQL injection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSRS (not the greatest) to give a basic entry selection for users, using a insert stored procedure and then passing the parameter as the value you want inserting. Not the most elegant but i found given my lack of .net and c# that it worked great.

[This is what got me started.](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/articles/sql-server-bi/26/using-sql-server-reporting-services-to-manage-data)

Answer (score 0):

1) Gavlaaa's suggestion of SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) is probably user-friendlier than using Excel as input...

((P.S. I have not tried this, but this suggests you can use Excel as input to SSRS: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/449194/How-to-import-Excel-data-as-input-in-SSRS ))

2) But just in case you really want to use Excel as input... consider SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) -- what we use.

This suggestion assumes you are on SQL Server 2005 or later. 
(If you're on SQL Server 2000, you would use DTS instead of SSIS.)

SSIS lets you import Excel spreadsheets into a SQL database, into a table.  You can then execute T-SQL command(s) like SELECT INTO to create a new table, and then export to Excel again.  ((We use SSIS to import Excel, validate & format using T-SQL, & export for validating & pre-formatting product data... then export it into a precise format for programmatic loading.))

However, SSIS expects the Excel spreadsheet to be imported to be in a predictable format:  for example, one column of numbers without decimals, or always with two decimal points... etc.  If you have extra columns they'd be skipped (with a metadata warning); if you have too few columns the file might import unpredictably (with failure to import, or at least a metadata warning); if the column is a different format (for example no decimals where decimals are assumed), then SSIS can get very wierd, like import THAT column with nulls on some-but-not-all rows (with NO METADATA WARNING, in those cases).

So, with SSIS importing from Excel, consistent column formatting is important.  ((We simplify that by making all columns pure text / no formatting in the Excel input spreadsheet that initially gets imported, then T-SQL CONVERT to specific datatype when desired, before exporting to the Excel output.))

To learn more about SSIS, try this link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137709(SQL.90).aspx

For a simple way to give SSIS a try, use the import/export wizard: 
in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), right-click on one of your databases, select "Tasks", then select "Export Data".  On the second dialog ("Choose a Destination"), scroll near the top of the "Destination" drop-down and find Excel.... and then on the "Save and Execute Package" dialog, select Save SSIS Package, and for now (to keep it simpler) select the "File System" radio button... to save your SSIS package as a windows file.

I can say more... if you're interested in SSIS.

3) If you still have some reason to actually change the WHERE clause in a SQL command, you can build a SELECT statement and then execute it using the EXEC command:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: I added a "P.S." with a link, for Excel as input to SSRS.